# How to add Dictionary as a Request Parameter For HTTPBody in NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I am creating one demo Web Services Code without using `AFNetworking` Framework.
My `HTTP` `Request` Parameter in `Dictionary`.
How can I set it on `HTTPBody`?

## MY Code is as follow

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = "Request Parameter";

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//  NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", json);

}] resume];
```

Comment: do you have any headers in the request might have possibility you are forgetting to add it?

Comment: like `Content-Type` or `Accept` ?

Comment: chekc once in backend developer what are other params need to add

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik :-I mailed you please check it.

Comment: ya i seen but i got the same error, ensure once your backend developer

Comment: i tried in multiple wways i get the same mesage check once in your

Comment: Oky,Thank you,For Your response

Comment: If We Use AFNetworking It is working Fine.

Comment: Other option is to convert your dictionary to string and post. Your backend needs to parse it back to some map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Got The Data

```
NSURL *stringwithUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"XXXX"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:stringwithUrl];
    [requestUrl setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value==",@"Key", nil];
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSString *mainString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *requestString = @"request=";

    NSString *finalString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:mainString];

    [requestUrl setHTTPBody:[finalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *sesion = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    [[sesion dataTaskWithRequest:requestUrl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    }]resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do like that With AFnetworking and Without Af Networking.

```
NSString *stringUrl = @"xxx";

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *myConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *myManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:myConfiguration];
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer *mySerilizer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc]init];
    [myManager setResponseSerializer:mySerilizer];

    NSDictionary *param = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value==",@"Token", nil];

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *requestParameter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:string forKey:@"request"];

    [manager POST:stringUrl parameters:requestParameter progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSError *error;
        if(!error)
        {

            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",dict);

        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
```

## Without Dictionary

```
NSString *urlString = @"xxxx";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    AFHTTPResponseSerializer *serilizer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc]init];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:serilizer];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value",@"key", nil];
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSError *error;
        if(!error)
        {
            NSDictionary *finalData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Final Data is %@",finalData);

        }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

## Without AFNetworking

```
 NSString *MyUrlString = @"xxxx";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MyUrlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"key=value";
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                            error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", json);

    }] resume];
```

Note:-Do not forget to put **resume**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition with my working code,

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:50.0];
[_request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; // Interact your backend developer for header
[_request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];// Interact your backend developer for header

[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error;
NSData *_inputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inputDictionary options:0 error:&error];
[_request setHTTPBody:_inputData];

NSURLSessionDataTask *_fetchData = [[[self class] session] dataTaskWithRequest:_request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        NSError* error;
        completionBlock(data,error,1);
    } else {
        completionBlock(data,error,0);
    }
}];
[_fetchData resume];
```